# Qt Creator: Button Click Signal to make a window pop- up

Tags: c++, qt, uibutton, window

I’m using Qt Creator's Qt Quick and as suggested in the tutorial I made different .qml for every button.

I want when the button is clicked to make a window pop- up. What should I write after

```
onClicked:
```

in the mouseArea.

Also how to make a second window (the pop- up one), what should I add to the project so I can design it like the main one?

I read that I have to make a class that inherits with QWidget but I need a bit more information.

A short example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as suggested in the tutorial I made different .qml for every button

Surely you mean "for every button *type*"!?

To launch a second window:

```
// Main.qml
Window {
    id: win
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Button {
        text: qsTr( "Open" )
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        onClicked: {
            var factory = Qt.createComponent( "Popup.qml" );
            factory.createObject( win );
        }
    }
}

// Popup.qml
Window {
    height: 240
    width: 320
    title: qsTr( "Popup" )
    visible: true

    Text {
        text: qsTr( "Hello" )
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

> I read that I have to make a class that inherits with QWidget

Do not mix QML and the Qt Widgets module unless you are extending/converting a legacy system, QML has been designed to replace Qt Widgets (at some point).